# ubuntu can be loaded but windows 10 could not be loaded

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I installed ubuntu in sdb5 and windows 10 in sda1 many years ago. Also I asked someone else to help me installed an Apple’s system. I used grub to load the systems. Days ago after windows 10 was upgraded it cannot be loaded anymore. I can choose Windows 10 item in grub but it could not be loaded. There is only a black screen with a underscore flashing in the up left corner. Ubuntu can still be loaded and I can check the files in the disks.

I searched the solutions on Internet. I tried to delete some files in the disk to have more space; I tried to edit the 40_custom file but they did not work. Windows 10 still could not be loaded.

I tried not to reinstall the system.

Does anyone has any ideas? Why it happened? It has been working well for many years. Thanks!

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. First thing to check is fast start up which sets hibernation flag. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions If BIOS install and only one drive, you may have to temporarily install Windows boot loader to MBR to boot Windows & repair it. Then restore grub with Ubuntu live installer and Boot-Repair or manually reinstall to MBR. Windows 10 not really best for dual boot in old BIOS/MBR configuration on one drive. You need two MBR or UEFI install.

Comment: Try grub's **Advanced Options for Ubuntu** submenu and picking **Recovery** option. Does this work to get you in?

Comment: @oldfred Thanks. I think I can understand the principle now. Just need to search for some shared experience to implement it. Yes my laptop is 6 years old now and the BIOS is quite old. Also there is an Apple’s system in C drive together with the Windows 10 so I have no idea if I need to do something for this. May I ask why I need 2 MBR or UEFI install?

Comment: @oldfred Sorry I just thought about it again. If grub can not load windows 10, would MBR be able to load it? I’m afraid the fast start up could not help here because the last time windows 10 was working was ended by an upgrade and then it failed to be loaded when restarted.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yes I can go into Ubuntu and the recovery Ubuntu. I just cannot go into Windows 10.

Comment: You do not have to have two MBR or UEFI, its just that Windows 10 may not boot from grub. Then you have to go thru installing Windows 10 bootloader to MBR, fix Windows, then restore grub. You will need both a Windows repair disk & Ubuntu live installer to make those MBR changes. If issue is just fast start up or chkdsk needed then Windows should start to boot, but you have to get into Safe Mode or its repair console which does not seem to work when grub chainloads into Windows, only direct boot from MBR. If you had Mac, did you create hybrid as it normally wants gpt, not MBR.